# List without nil in result Lisp

Tags: lisp

I have to delete all occurences of an element in a list from all levels.
My code is:

```
(defun sterge(e l)
   (cond
    ((and (atom l) (equal e l)) nil)
    ((atom l) (list l))
    (t (append (apply #'list (mapcar #' (lambda (l) (sterge e l)) l))))
  )
)
(defun sterg(e l)
  (car (sterge e l))
)
```

When I give:

```
(sterg 1 '(1 2 1 ( 1 2 1( 1 (1) (1)) (1) 3) (1)(2)))
```

it shows me the output:

```
 ((2 (2 (NIL NIL) NIL 3) NIL (2)))
```

How to delete that nil?? Thank you.

Comment: If you remove 1 from (1) you should get (correctly) an empty list, which is NIL. And this is exactly what you are getting from your function. In other words, the function is correct! To be convinced of this, write `(remove 1 '(1))` (using the standard function `remove`) in REPL.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `nil`, consider returning `sterge` applied to the rest of the entity `l`. `mapcar` is not the best way to approach this problem; a recursive function is better (unless the assignment specifies using `mapcar`, of course.)

Hint: Treat `l` as if it were a list and test `(car l)`, e.g., `(atom (car l))`, apply `sterge` to `(cdr l)`.

Comment: It gives me Stack overflow (stack size 31744).

Comment: You probably need to ensure that `l` isn't a null list to terminate the recursion. :-)